# Opencart 3 extending Twig (access Twig environment from a controller)

Tags: twig, opencart-3

In Opencart 3, is there a way to access twig environment from a controller?
working with OC v3.0.3.1
I am trying to add a custom function which I could use in the template.
I am using the documentation [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html)

Tried adding the following to the controller:

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DIR_TEMPLATE);                
$config = array('autoescape' => false);

$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, $config);
     $function= new \Twig_SimpleFunction('foo', function(){ 
         return 'bar'; 
     });
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

in the template I have:

```
{{ foo() }}
```

Getting:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "foo" function in ...

Comment: Seems you need to ajust the following file `upload/system/library/template/twig.php`

Comment: Yeah, looks likes it is impossible to achieve what I want with the current design. Extending twig would be useful for extension devs.