# Using a PHP function in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a PHP code to add a new class for my Twig template in my common controller in: "opencart\htdocs\catalog\controller\common\cart.php"

The code should check if the Device is Mobile or not.

```
function onStart()
{
    // Anonymous Class only working on PHP7
    $this['code'] = new class {
       
       public function MobileDetect() {

    return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo
|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i"

, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);

}

    };

}
```

But now I don´t know how to address that function correctly from my twig side at:

`opencart\htdocs\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\cart.twig`

I tried something like this, but it didn´t seem to work:

```
{% if code.MobileDetect() is defined %}
```

If a device is mobile I want to use a completely different HTML construct.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343041/opencart-3-extending-twig-access-twig-environment-from-a-controller)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is create your own Twig function:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#functions

So using their examples you should be able to do something like

```
$function = new \Twig\TwigFunction('MobileDetect', function () {
    return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo
    |fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i"
    , $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
});
$twig->addFunction($filter);
```

Then call it like

```
{% if MobileDetect() %}
```